# Measures on natural numbers. How many?

Tags: measure-theory

Given a positive unbounded sequence $\{a_n\}$, I define a measure 
$$\mu(Q)=
\sum_{n\in Q}a_n,
$$
where $Q$ is a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$.
 This measure is finitely additive and turns $\mathbb{N}$ into a sigma finite measure space. Is it true for any sequence $a$ ?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I think it is actually true. This proposition seems obvious to me.  Moreover, it is easy to show that such measures form the set of the continuum cardinality. Nevertheless,, I might be completely wrong.

Comment: "[...]and zero otherwise." So you are saying $\mu(\mathbb{N})=0$? You have to be a bit more careful.

Comment: I still don't quite understand what `$0,\quad\text{otherwise}$` means. What underlying measurable space are we using?

Comment: If your space is ${\Bbb N}$ the "otherwise" part is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true for any non-negative sequence.

You have probably encountered these sequences before.  Consider any discrete probability distribution (a binomial distribution, or a Poisson distribution, for instance).  Then the pmf  $f$ has the properties that you describe, and induces a measure (specifically a probability  measure) $P$ on the whole of $\mathbb{N}$ by:
$$
P(A)=\sum_{k\in A}f(k).$$

In addition to the usual axioms for a measure, probability measures also have to satisfy the axion $P(\Omega)=1$.  Thus, we have the familiar result that any non-negative sequence $\langle a_{n}\vert n\in\mathbb{N}\rangle$ (i.e., a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$) satisfying 
$$
\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}a_{k}=1$$
is a pmf for some probability distribution. In the general measure theoretic setting, the same reasoning holds, but without the need to worry about convergence or that extra axiom.

(Note that the measures you define in this way are not absolutely continuous with respect to to the usual Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$, so no Radon-Nikodym derivatives (density functions) exist.  But this doesn't mean that the measures are in any way illegitimate.)